# How to retrieve the last day of last month in a certain format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to retrieve the last day of the last month in MS-SQL-Server

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

This gives me the result

```
2013-03-31 23:59:59.000
```

Now I need to change this format so that I receive it like this

```
mm/dd/yy
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Each month last day or current month last day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL server 
try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),101)
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),1)
```

Comment: the first is for mm/dd/yyyy
the second is for mm/dd/yy

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date) + 1, 0) - 1, 101)
```

Output:

```
04/30/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Set date format to day/month/year.
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
GO
DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '31/12/2008 09:01:01.1234567';
SELECT @datevar;
GO
-- Result: 2008-12-31 09:01:01.123
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
GO
DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '12/31/2008 09:01:01.1234567';
SELECT @datevar;
GO
-- Result: Msg 241: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time -- from character string.

GO
```